# Are schema:domainIncludes and rdfs:domain (as well as schema:rangeIncludes and rdfs:range) the same?

Tags: schema, rdf, schema.org, rdfs, n-triples

Schema.org both **defines** and **uses** the predicates named `domainIncludes` and `rangeIncludes` to relate types to properties (i.e. `<schema:name> <schema:domainIncludes> <schema:Person>` and `<schema:name> <schema:rangeIncludes> <schema:Text>`).

However in [RDF Schema 1.1's specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/), the predicates `domain` and `range` are already defined (giving `<schema:name> <rdfs:domain> <schema:Person>` and `<schema:name> <schema:range> <schema:Text>`).

My question boils down to: **are schema.org's `domainIncludes` and `rangeIncludes` predicates equivalent to the RDFS `domain` and `range` predicates?**

And if so:

- Why does schema.org define them in the first place and not just use the predicates provided by the RDF standard? It already makes use of other RDFS defined predicates such as `rdfs:label` and `rdfs:comment`. Was this a stylistic choice? (Did they not like the names "domain" and "range"?)
- Why is this relationship between the predicates not defined using `owl:equivalentProperty` or  an equivalent? Schema.org should be explicit when creating predicates that are already defined by accepted standards such as RDFS 1.1, especially given its mission is structuring and standardising the web.

Otherwise remain a big fan of schema.org : )

Comment: The definition of `domainIncludes` states: *"Relates a property to a class that is (one of) the type(s) the property is expected to be used on."* - the important part here is **(one of) the type(s)** - so, this is basically some kind of union/disjunction. With RDFS and by using `rdfs:domain` you cannot do this, because having multiple types as `rdfs:domain` means the intersection of those, e.g. if you have `p rdfs:domain A. p rdfs:domain B` and a triple `a p b` then `a` belongs to `A` **and** also to `B`.

Comment: And for proper disjunction in RDFS, you need OWL language to create a class expression `A or B` with the built-in predicate `owl:unionOf`

Comment: this discussion, unfortunately, is not correct. schema enables `@Class` specifications that are fully-qualified targets for `@Property` specifications using `domainIncludes` and `rangeIncludes`. It is entirely possible to using reasoning when using those schema types.

Comment: “It is entirely possible to using reasoning when using those schema types.” Sure, but it’s not the same as OWL domain and range reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does schema.org define them in the first place and not just use the predicates provided by the RDF standard?

Schema.org doesn't want you to do inferencing using certain properties. If I knew that

```
<schema:name> <rdfs:domain> <schema:Person>
```

then whenever I saw a `<schema:name>` defined for an object, I could infer that the object was of type `<schema:Person>`. Schema.org uses `<schema:name>` for lots of things so uses `<schema:domainIncludes>` to indicate how you *could* or *should* use it but doesn't lock it down.

> Why is this relationship between the predicates not defined using owl:equivalentProperty or an equivalent?

This is a policy issue for schema.org! My guess is that, like many general purpose ontologies (e.g. [Semantic Sensor Network vocab](https://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-ssn/)), they like to keep weak semantics to allow for flexibility of application over the kind of strictness you're talking about that you need for inference.

Comment: Thanks, this distinction makes sense to me.

Comment: IMHO the above is not correct. See comment to question.

Comment: If you can explain why the reasoning is wrong in the form of an alternative answer, I'd happily consider it @JayGray

Comment: Will do. Am currently discussing this subject with another SME, so timing is good. We have several large `@Class` instances that work on GSDTT and have been processed by a reasoner (HermIT); need to determine how best to prune for a stackoverflow answer. May take 3-4 days to document the update.

Comment: I’m looking forward to this too! Will be helpful with my use of schema.org.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at RDF/OWL as a distributed DB,
and an ontology as the DB Schema,
then this explanation might make sense to you:

If you look at the definition of [rdfs:domain](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_domain),
you find:

> Where a property `P` has more than one [rdfs:domain](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_domain) property,
> then the resources denoted by subjects of triples
> with predicate `P` are instances of all the classes
> stated by the [rdfs:domain](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_domain) properties.

So if you have more then one domain,
**all** those must be true! 
*RDFS* -> **AND**

If you have multiple [schema:domainIncludes](http://schema.org/domainIncludes),
**at least one** must be true. 
*schema.org (& DC)* -> **OR**

I find that in (DB-)practice, one almost always wants the later approach (*OR*).

All this is the same for [rdfs:range](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_range) and [schema:rangeIncludes](http://schema.org/rangeIncludes).

---

Addition (January 2024):

There are actually two versions of the `*Includes` properties
in widely used ontologies:

- ***schema.org*** (`http://schema.org/`): 
  [schema:domainIncludes](http://schema.org/domainIncludes) & [schema:rangeIncludes](http://schema.org/rangeIncludes)
- ***DC Metadata Terms*** (`http://purl.org/dc/dcam/`): 
  [dcam:domainIncludes](http://purl.org/dc/dcam/domainIncludes) & [dcam:rangeIncludes](http://purl.org/dc/dcam/rangeIncludes)

They seem to have the same meaning,
as far as I can decipher.

Sadly, neither of the two links to the other. :/